# Supply a string as stdin for the child_process.spawn option

Tags: node.js, child-process, node-streams

I want to use a promisified alternative to `child_process.spawn` so I am using `promisify-child-process`. So I am wondering how I can supply the `stdin` option. I tried it with a `stream.Readable` but the following error occurs:

```
(node:42158) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value "Readable {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 1,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, ta..." is invalid for option "stdio"
…
```

I am using the following code:

```js
import { spawn } from "promisify-child-process";
import { Readable } from "stream";

const stdin = Readable.from([ "test string" ]);
await spawn("command", [], { stdio: [ stdin, "pipe", "pipe" ], encoding: "utf8", shell: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had to do this, you can do:

```
const stdin = Readable.from([ "test string" ]);
const process = spawn("command", [], { stdio: [ stdin, "pipe", "pipe" ], encoding: "utf8", shell: true });

stdin.pipe(process.stdin)
```

Or, you can just use `@await/spawn` (from npm):

```
const spawn = require("@await/spawn");

await spawn("command", { input: "test string" });
```